# unable to upload dicom images upon click event - webMango

Tags: javascript, jquery, dicom

I am using webMango and I modified the html syntax to upload DICOM images upon a clicking the browse button.

As of now I have hardcoded the value of the params[] variable. It still does not work. Upon selecting random files, I still get an empty DICOM viewer and no images are uploaded.

Also, even if I initialize params[] to the actual images, the viewer gives an incorrect view the images. The sagittal and coronal views are not shown.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>webMango</title>
        <script src="mango.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>    
            var params = [];
                    $(document).ready(function(){
        var filetarget="[[";
            $("#uploadFile").change(function(event){
                $dir = $("#directory").val();
                $dir = "data";
                for( var i=0; i<event.target.files.length; i++) {
                filetarget = filetarget + "'" + $dir + "/" +  $(this).val() + "'";
                if(i != event.target.files.length -1)
                filetarget= filetarget + ",";
                }
            filetarget = filetarget + "]]";
            //params["images"] = "\"" + filetarget + "\"";
            params["images"]="[['data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm','data/IM-0001-0244.dcm']]";
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is an example use of webMango.</p>
        <label> Directory root </label> <input type="text" id="directory"/> <br/>
        <input type="file" id="uploadFile" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory/>
        <div style="width:800px;" class="mango" id="mango"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not designed to work with Jquery, but with a small modification, I think you can do what you want.  First, in `mango.js`, remove this line:

```
window.onload = runMango; // it's at the bottom
```

Next, see the below example use with JQuery.  Note the call to `runMango()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>webMango</title>
        <script src="mango2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>        
            var params = [];        
            $(document).ready(function() {
                params["images"] = "['data/sample_image.nii.gz']";
                runMango();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is an example use of webMango.</p>
        <div style="width:800px;" class="mango"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Also, even if I initialize params[] to the actual images, the viewer
>   gives an incorrect view the images. The sagittal and coronal views are
>   not shown.

Not sure about this one.  I noticed all your images references are to the same file, so maybe that had something to do with it.  Make sure your series contains references to all the different files in the series.

Comment: The jQuery part worked perfectly. thank you so much ! is it not permissible for the params["images"] to accept absolute paths? I gave a path like - "[['F:\data\IMG-01-001.dcm']]", it says no image file found ?

Comment: No, the security constraints don't permit it to reference the local file system like that.  It needs relative URL references.

Comment: Ah! okay. So I need to provide relative paths then. thank you !